# Why is my VBA copy/paste of web page table to Excel truncated at the top of the table

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to copy a table from a web page into an Excel worksheet with VBA.  The web page has only one table.  See below for my code.  I am using a slightly modified version of an answer posted by QHarr in July of 2018.

My code runs without error, however there is nothing in Cell(1, 1) in my target worksheet.  I was expecting a copy of the table from the web page. (Manual select, copy, paste works just fine.)  Once I get this working, it will be part of a loop to fetch and process a lot of pages/tables.

In the Immediate Window, "Debug.Print hTable.outerHTML" shows that the table tag, the title row, the headings row, and the beginning (tr, and first 2 td) of the first data row are missing.  The rest of the table rows, thru  appear to be present.

I'm a bit surprised that the top of the table is missing.  To me, it suggests that something ran out of space and the "oldest" data got pushed off the top of the stack.

I'm assuming that my empty worksheet is due to the incomplete table definition.

My question is, how do I get past this problem?  I am very new to VBA.

=====

My code so far...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable, clipboard As Object
    Dim travURL As String
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Point to hyperlink
    travURL = Cells(5, 18).Hyperlinks(1).Address
        
    With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate (travURL)
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        'Set html = .Document
        'With html
        With .Document
            Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
            Debug.Print hTable.outerHTML
            Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
            clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of VBA have you tried using Power Query to import the table?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the URL?

Comment: In my journey to get this far, I did run across Power Query, but have not gotten any further with it.  I need a good sample (or instructions) to get started.  If this code provs to be a dead end, I will try Power Query next.  I need to be able to drive it from code.  This little test is just one page of 28 that I will need to access each time I run the wrappering code.

Comment: I found a page where the table only has 3 data rows (plus title and header), instead of 16.  The code ran to completion without error.  There is still no table pasted into my worksheet.  This time, however, Debug.Print shows the entire table from <table> to </table>.  The URL (might require authentication) for the shorter page is...  https://www.bridgebase.com/myhands/hands.php?traveller=M-1614039125-VD%3Ajlhoweiii%3A1614039125%3A13&username=jlhoweiii   I can post the page source for the shorter table if it would help.

Comment: Most of the pages I will need to process will have 16 data rows.  So, it looks like I have 2 problems...  1) The truncated results from the larger page, and 2) why I can't paste the copied table into my worksheet.

Comment: I have an account now without knowing anything about Bridge ;-) Your code do what you want with the given link. The whole table was pasted, include headlines. Interesting aproach with the clipboard. Quite unorthodox, but works in this case.

Comment: Interesting that it works for you, because it doesn't paste anything into my target worksheet. What would be the more orthodox method?  I just want the table pasted into my worksheet.  I already have code to process the pasted worksheet.

Comment: The 16 line tables I found have no table tag with the data. They are a little horror div tag collection. Extremely cluttered. Can you post one or better two URLs of 16 line tables you want to read out? The more orthodox aproach is to use the DOM (Document Object Model) and read out every specific needed value. In many cases like tables it's possible to use loops for that.

Comment: Here's another URL...

https://www.bridgebase.com/myhands/hands.php?traveller=M-1615241617-M_2_0008683197&username=jlhoweiii

All of the page source I have browsed show one set of <table> </table> tags.  The <table> tag is at the end of a very long line.

Comment: More googling and I solved my first problem.  The Immediate Window does  have a fixed size.  My 16 row table exceeds that size, so the oldest (top) rows in the window are lost.

I changed Debug.Print to write to a txt file.  The whole table from <table> to </table> is present in the txt file.  I changed the code to wrapper the table with <html> and </html>.

The remaining question is why do I see "??" in my worksheet rather than the table?

Comment: More experimenting...  The file I wrote as a debug aid can be manually copied, opened with Get From Text/CSV, imported with code -- all produce the desired table.  What is wrong with my attempt to use the clipboard?
            Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
            clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial 
These 4 lines of code just place "??" in the worksheet.

Comment: Still more experimenting...  Apparently my clipboard problem is due to MS breaking MSForms when it moved to some combination of Windows 10, 64-bit, and maybe the newer versions of MSO.  My code was fine.  The work around for me was to make sure that Windows Explorer was closed. (Can someone explain this?).  I found many references to a module that replaces the MSForms.DataObject.PutInClipboard with a module that uses Windows SetClipboardData.  I have not been able to make that work yet.  See...  https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/clipboard-copy-vba-code-not-working-in-windows-10.37126/